# What is the windows cmd command equivalent to ubuntu command timeout 5s a.exe < input.txt

Tags: windows, ubuntu, command-line, g++

I am developing an online judge for my university. I need to timeout every program after 5 seconds for measuring time limit. my input is input.txt file and i am compiling and getting output in ubuntu by these commands

```
g++ -lm tle.cpp
timeout 5s a.exe < input.txt
```

These commands allow cpu to run programs for only 5 seconds. Now I need equivalent commands for Windows cmd.

**Edit :**

This Question is different from previous one as windows timeout process is different from ubuntu timeout process. Windows timeout process just waits but not set a definite time for execution. if execution is done before timeout then windows timeout still waits where ubuntu timeout set a definite time for program execution and terminates after execution but does not wait though program is terminated. So i want to stop waiting if execution is finished.

Comment: Yeah . This should be reopened  As i worked hard  to find the solution .

Comment: Voted to reopen. As techraf noted, we're a bit different than forums - Super User is a Q&A site. You've found an answer to your question, it's not only okay to post it as an answer but it's also encouraged: it makes it easier for others with this problem to realize that you've actually found a solution. Moreover, you'll be getting reputation for every upvote on that answer too. Please post an answer with your solution and remove it from question.

Comment: Yet it is closed @gronostaj

Comment: so why don't just post the answer on the other duplicate question?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I should get some sleep ;)

Comment: I see you posted your answer to the marked duplicate question.  Please edit your question to remove the answer.  Thanks for contributing to Super User.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution :**

By The Way I have found my solution. In windows it needs to make three batch files

**process.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
start   /b cm.bat
start  cmd.exe /c run.bat
EXIT
```

**cm.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
a.exe < input.txt > out.txt
taskkill /im a.exe /f
taskkill /im cmd.exe /f
EXIT
```

**run.bat**

```
@ECHO off
timeout /t 5
taskkill /im a.exe /f 
taskkill /im cmd.exe /f

EXIT
```

Now Run process.bat . it will start both cm.bat and run.bat simultaneously/parallely. When a.exe from cm.bat terminates; cm.bat kills run.bat and thus it will work as ubuntu timeout.